# My List<bool> doesn't update when value in origin change

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having trouble getting items in my `List` to update, anybody have any idea why this code isn't working? `refScript1.selfCollide` is a referenced bool from my `PlayerProximityHitboxes` script. Those bools are being updated in an `OnTriggerEnter` and `OnTriggerExit` event in another script. I'm pretty new to lists so I feel like I must have missed something obvious.

```cs
public class HitboxManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool frontCollide, rightCollide, backCollide, leftCollide;
    public PlayerProximityHitboxes refScript1, refScript2, refScript3, refScript4;
    public List<bool> hitboxDir = new List<bool>();

    void Start()
    {
        hitboxDir.Add(refScript1.selfCollide);
        hitboxDir.Add(refScript2.selfCollide);
        hitboxDir.Add(refScript3.selfCollide);
        hitboxDir.Add(refScript4.selfCollide);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //referencing the index doesn't seem to work, here's my attempt at doing so
        //frontCollide = hitboxDir[0];
        //rightCollide = hitboxDir[1];
        //backCollide = hitboxDir[2];
        //leftCollide = hitboxDir[3];

        //this works, but I want to be able to sort by indexes so I can reorder them.
        frontCollide = refScript1.selfCollide;
        rightCollide = refScript2.selfCollide;
        backCollide = refScript3.selfCollide;
        leftCollide = refScript4.selfCollide;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which error you get?

Comment: bool objects are value types  which means they will be copied into list box on Start like "true, false..etc" , either you need to clear the list and add them again in every frame update or use a reference type value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You saving value to the list, and if it changed in the `refscript`, it will not affect your value in the list. You have to save the link to the script, and then get value from it.

```
    ...
    public List<PlayerProximityHitboxes> hitboxDir = new List<PlayerProximityHitboxes>();
    ...
    void Start()
    {
        hitboxDir.Add(refScript1);
        hitboxDir.Add(refScript2);
        hitboxDir.Add(refScript3);
        hitboxDir.Add(refScript4);
    }
    void Update()
    {
        frontCollide = hitboxDir[0].selfCollide;
        rightCollide = hitboxDir[1].selfCollide;
        backCollide = hitboxDir[2].selfCollide;
        leftCollide = hitboxDir[3].selfCollide;
    }
```

See here for more infor about Ref and Value types http://net-informations.com/faq/general/valuetype-referencetype.htm

Comment: Yes, this worked! Thank you, I had no idea you could just use the reference type as the stand-in type for the list.

Answer (score 4):

**Boolean is
not referenced**:  [Reference to documentation explaining bool is a struct.](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/bool)

---

You have actually described your problem exactly in words "referenced bool". You are copying the value of `boolean`. In memory this is single "bit" which is coppied and that replaces the value. When you do:

```cs
//Simple types (all structs, ints, booleans, chars, bytes, ...)
bool a = true;
bool b = a;                  //Passed value to variable
a = false;
Console.WriteLine(b);        //You will get `True` here

//Compared to some class/reference to classes
PlayerProximityHitboxes a = new PlayerProximityHitboxes();
PlayerProximityHitboxes b = a;
b.DoSomeUpdate();            //both `a` and `b` are same object
Console.WriteLine(b);        //Same output as for `a`
```

---

What you can do is keep reference to objects in a `list` and check for its bool value/update it:

```cs
public class HitboxManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool frontCollide, rightCollide, backCollide, leftCollide;
    public PlayerProximityHitboxes refScript1, refScript2, refScript3, refScript4;
    public List<bool> hitboxDir = new List<bool>();

    void Start()
    {
        hitboxDir.Add(refScript1);
        hitboxDir.Add(refScript2);
        hitboxDir.Add(refScript3);
        hitboxDir.Add(refScript4);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        frontCollide = hitboxDir[0].selfCollide;
        rightCollide = hitboxDir[1].selfCollide;
        backCollide = hitboxDir[2].selfCollide;
        leftCollide = hitboxDir[3].selfCollide;
    }
```